# In DSP, are there alternatives to MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, discrete-signals

I have DSP in my curriculum. I kindly request suggestions on alternatives to MATLAB. Ideally, alternatives that are not as "heavy", megabyte-wise.

Comment: See [octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/)

Comment: Why is "downloading size" a problem?  I would expect cost to be much more important.

Comment: As I know MATLAB stands in GB and with my Internet it will take days of time to download. thats why I am looking for some other alternative tool .

Comment: This question is [cross-posted](http://askubuntu.com/questions/297304/similar-tools-for-matlab) on Ask Ubuntu, and has good answers there. Stack Exchange generally disallows cross-posting questions, so I'm closing this one.

Comment: @Phonon Yeah I did it for better answers. Different people and and they will give Different suggestions & that can help me to get the best.

Comment: It's a legit question.  I voted to re-open.

Comment: What would be nice is a way to write DSP code for the product-release level that has efficient utilities like some found in MATLAB and can be tested with tools like we get in MATLAB.  Right now, I have to write the algorithm in MATLAB, test it on a `.wav` file, debug the motherfucker with some nice tools in MATLAB and, once I am satisfied that the algorithm is working correctly, ***then*** translate it to C or C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Octave is a good option. Some people call it as a free version of Matlab. 
I found Wolfram Mathematica to be of great use. It seems to be much more powerful than Matlab, not to mention, simpler to use.

Comment: thank you I have installed Octave and Scilab. Which is good among these two ?

Comment: They are both good. It depends on how well you know to use them. I prefer Octave. It is a personal preference.

Comment: could you post a good startup link for octave ? Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I've been using [NumPy/SciPy](https://scipy.org/) for everything.  It doesn't have as many functions/features as Matlab, but the Python language is much nicer to work with, and it's free and open-source, so it's getting better all the time.

Python is very modular, so depending on which features you want, it may be a large download or a small download.  I don't care about download or installation size, so I use the [Python(x,y)](https://python-xy.github.io/) package on Windows, which is based on the Spyder IDE, and includes lots of packages I may or may not use (117 MB).  The bare minimum to try it out is [Python](https://www.python.org/getit/) and [NumPy](https://pypi.org/project/numpy/), which is about 20 MB + 3 MB.

[pyzo](https://pyzo.org/install_packages.html) is another collection of Python packages for scientific computing, for Win/Linux/Mac, at 79 MB, with [IEP](https://pyzo.org/iep.html) IDE.  I've never tried IEP.  "[Spyder, PTK and IEP](https://web.archive.org/web/20160114060930/https://code.google.com/p/iep/wiki/Alternatives) are IDE's that provide a Matlab-like interface. The development of each of these started before the release of any of the other."

See [NumPy for Matlab users](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html) and my answer to [Moving to Python (SciPy and NumPy) for Scientific Computing](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/198069/7525) on Programmers.SE.

Comment: I will try this for sure. Thank you for your valuable time and suggestions . :)

Answer (score 2):

I have found Scilab and sage as somewhat better alternative to the MATLAB.

For Sage: http://www.sagemath.org/

For Scilab : https://www.scilab.org/

Comment: You can also use https://cloud.sagemath.com/ online for free, where Sage, Scilab, and Octave are all available, at least from the terminal.  There is no download at all, so this might be useful for you.